# Unity 3d. Input field не выводит некоторые заглавные буквы на русском языке

Tags: unity3d

Unity v 2018.2.2f1 personal
UI InputField не вводит заглавные "ЙКЕНГЗВАПОЛДЖМИБ"

Comment: мб проблема со шрифтами?меняли их?

Comment: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/some-capital-non-latin-characters-do-not-appear-when-typing-them-in-the-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это баг новой версии Unity. Сами столкнулись с этой проблемой. Ждём фиксов.